# "libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: centos, администрирование

При запуске сервиса выдаёт такую ошибку. Где libjawt.so взять, или с чем он устанавливается?

Centos 7.

Comment: что это за «сервис», каким образом он появился в вашем компьютере?

Comment: Это игровой сервер, использующий Java Native Interface.

Comment: ещё раз: каким образом «сервис» появился в вашем компьютере?

Comment: Я его сам "закачал". Этот "сервис" запускается через .sh файл.

Comment: понятно. по поводу проблем с его использованием логичнее всего будет обратиться в то место, откуда вы его «закачали».

Answer (score 1):

найти пакет, который предоставляет указанный файл, с помощью `yum` (пакетного менеджера, используемого по умолчанию в *redhat-осно́вных* дистрибутивах) можно так:

```
$ yum whatprovides libjawt.so
```

в имеющейся у меня под рукой версии *centos* ответ получился таким:

```
...
libgcj-4.4.7-16.el6.i686 : Java runtime library for gcc
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Other       : libjawt.so
```

т.е., требуется пакет `libgcj` из репозитория `base`. в вашей версии это может быть совсем другой пакет.

Comment: "No matches found".

Comment: *No matches found* — значит, ни в одном из подключенных репозиториев нет пакетов, предоставляющих такой файл.

Comment: Если бы у вас не был установлен base, как можно было бы узнать, в каком он пакете?

Comment: на машине, в которой я выполнял команду, установлена совсем другая версия centos, и, главное, подключены совсем другие репозитории, нежели у вас. вообще большинство пакетов на этой машине собраны для архитектуры x86_64, а найденный пакет собран для архитектуры i686.

Comment: Тогда каким образом следует искать отсутствующие файлы, если "No matches found"?